# Javascript set title onload?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

Is there anyway to set the title of a website via JS onload? I wrote this but I'm not sure where it's incorrect:

```
function my_code(){
document.title = "The new title goes here.";
}

window.onload=my_code();
```

The page title is static by the way.

Edit: The reason why I want to do it this way is because I'm writing a Safari Extension for a website that does not include  tags so I wanted to insert one via JS.

Comment: why do you want to do this? the user won't be able to see it.

Comment: Why not just put the title in the title tag as normal?

Comment: I'm writing a safari extension that changes a website's layout and there is no title tag, so I wanted my script to add one via JS onload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to wait for the `load` event.

Just write `document.title = ...` anywhere.

Comment: I forgot to specify that there are not <title> tags already on the page. I assume this only works with <title> tags present, and would instead need to first insert them then change the value?

Comment: You presume incorrectly.  The `title` property has nothing to do with the tag; it's just a property of the document that the tag sets.

Comment: So without a title tag, the code you posted should set the title no matter what?

Comment: Ah, it's working now. I had an error in my Extension code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*If* you want to change the title after the page loaded, you have to assign a function *reference* to `onload` (your function assigns the return value of `my_code`):

```
window.onload = my_code;
```

However, you most certainly can set the title without waiting for the `load` event.

I'm not familiar with Safari extensions, but you should also make sure that `window` actually refers to the page's `window`.

Comment: There are no <title> tags on the website I am working on, as I'm writing a Safari Extension that would change the title of a certain website. I think this would only work if there were <title> tags already in place.

Comment: @Charlie: The `title` element is mandatory. If it does not exists, I think most browsers will correct this an add an empty one.

Comment: Safari does not add an empty one, it instead displays the URL as the title. Can JS insert the <title> tags after the <head> tags (yes, they are there :D ) and then perform the `document.title`?

Answer (score -1):

solved your question

script:

```
function load_title(){
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    var text_title = "SUNDAGEEKS ツ The aspiring white-hat hacker/security awareness playground ≪ SUNDAGEEKS :: INDOXPLOIT";
        document.title = text_title;
}
var title_js = document.createElement("title");
    window.onload = load_title();
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(title_js);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).